# Url específica no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou reescrevendo um site usando Django. Trata-se de um blog e preciso que as urls sejam as mesmas do site antigo para que o site não perca ranqueamento nos motores de busca. Qual seria a melhor forma de tratar esse problema?

Comment: O blog atual é de que tipo/tecnologia? Wordpress? Existe um esquema de URLs definido para o blog atual, ou um arquivo .htaccess com uma definição de expressões regulares?

Comment: O blog atual é em wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Na prática é necessário criar a mesma estrutura de URLs do blog atual no [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/) do Django.

Abaixo um exemplo de uma definição de URLs (copiado da documentação do Django). É necessário fazer as adaptações necessárias para o seu novo blog, se baseando na estrutura de URLs do blog atual. O URL dispatcher utiliza [expressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) para definir os caminhos:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

O primeiro passo é identificar qual é exatamente a estrutura de URLs atual. Dependendo do tipo/tecnologia do blog atual, ela pode estar em arquivos de configuração, ou dentro do arquivo .htaccess. Se não tiver essa estrutura disponível, também pode tentar descobrir "no olho", observando os URLs que aparecem no browser.

O segundo passo é replicar essa estrutura no URL dispatcher (normalmente fica no arquivo urls.py).